# Bootstrap 4 and Semantic UI could be used together?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

Bootstrap 4 and Semantic UI could be used together?

Semantic UI's components are more than Bootstrap's,so I want Semantic UI to be supplements of Bootstrap,is it ok?

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend it. There will be conflicts if you use the full framework as neither are "namespaced." For instance, both set styles on plain `h1` tags. Therefore depending on how your browser loads the CSS, you may end up with different styles than you expect.

If you are planning on making custom builds of both, or specific builds of one or the other, you may be able to make it work. Neither framework is designed to work in conjunction with others.